# How to find RGB value of a bounded region in an image using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose i have image and need to find where i draw a rectangle using,

cv2.rectangle(image,(250,70),(150,45),(0,255,0),5)

on an image?

How to find particularly values of this rectangle in cv/python?

Comment: What do you mean you want to find the RGB value? A bounded region will have many RGB values corresponding to the many pixels that exist in the bounded region. Are you trying to extract the bounded region?

Comment: As in i have many colors in an image and i particularly bounded purple region and i need to find it's RGB value. That's it.

Comment: So the region in the bounding box would be one solid color?

Comment: Yes it is having any color for time being i said Purple color . Can we do any such operation on box particularly to find RGB values?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to extract the RGB value of the region in the bounding box.

Assuming you read the image with CV2, then the image is already represented as BGR. All you'd have to do is find a point in the bounding box and extract the BGR value of the point. Note I'm using BGR because that is how OpenCV reads images.

Using the bounding box vertices you used, just calculate a midpoint in the bounding box and extract the BGR value of that midpoint in the image.

```
# midpoint is ((y_max - y_min) // 2 + y_min, (x_max - x_min) // 2 + x_min)
point = ((70 - 45) // 2 + 45, (250 - 150) // 2 + 150)

b, g, r = image[point]
```

If the pixels in the bounding boxes have varying colors though, this method won't work. In that case, maybe you want to get the mean BGR values.

```
# image[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]
region = image[45:70, 150:250]

b, g, r = np.mean(region, axis=(0, 1))
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting typo error there.
    b, g, r = image[point]
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Your `image` object apparently isn't an numpy matrix. It's a boolean. You sure you read your image right? It should be something like `image = cv2.imread('path/to/image.png')`

Comment: I did ,

i=cv2.imread('path\image.jpg')
im=cv2.resize(i,(1020,880))
op=cv2.rectangle(image,(250,70),(150,45),(0,255,0),5)
rgb=cv2.imwrite("doc.jpg",op)
point = ((70 - 45) // 2 + 45, (250 - 150) // 2 + 150)
b, g, r = rgb[point] # Error on this line

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` will return a boolean. What you want to do is `b, g, r = im[point]`, where `im` is your resized image. Technically, you don't really even need the bounding box rectangle code since you just need the coordinates of the bounding box.